Schengen Multi entry visa
I have a multi entry type C visa issued from Spain for 6 months duration ending in Nov 24. I have already been to Spain on my first trip and Norway and Finland for my 2nd trip for tourism purposes. I have to travel to Romania for business meeting now. Can i use the same visa?

@Henriksupportsthecommunity just to add that i am Indian national so will this have any impact?

@TarunG What makes you think you might not be able to?

From the (planned) date of arrival in Romania, how many days were you in the Schengen Area in the previous 180 days period? Please add this information to your question.

@MarkJohnson previously in last 180 days i have travelled a total of 15 days

Then you have 75 days left or until the day that the visa expires. (This assumes that the duration field states '90' or '-')

Please add the the amount of days left in the 180 days period, into your question.

As one of the answers to that question says "Yes, Schengen type C visa are simply short-stay visas. Nowhere does the sticker say “tourism”. ", why would your nationality affect that?

As long as:

You are within the limit of number of entries (none here since it's a multiple-entry visa)
You are between the start and end date of validity of the visa as shown on the sticker
The total amount of days you stay in the Schengen Area (days you arrive and days you leave included) is within the "duration" of the visa shown on the sticker
You are within the 90/180 limit (on any day you hare in the Schengen Area, you haven't been in the Schengen Area on more than 90 days within the last 180)
You only perform activities permissible under a visitor visa (doesn't matter if the visa was issues for tourism or business)

Then you're good to go.
Remember, each time you enter they can ask for the usual evidence: reason for the trip, itinerary, return ticket, etc. The evidence is not necessarily the same for a business trip and tourism.
Of course, a visa is not a guarantee you will be allowed in either: if they suspect you're not meeting the conditions of the visa they can always refuse entry.
